# button not being displayed on Pycharm (using the Tkinter module)?. This is my code but I cant seem to edit and format the button as I would like to

Tags: python, button, tkinter, pycharm

```
import Tkinter as tk

import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)

frame.pack()

def Alberta():
    webbrowser.open_new(r"https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-CA&mid=%2Fm%2F0j95&gl=CA&ceid=CA%3Aen")

def BC():
    webbrowser.open_new(r"https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-CA&mid=%2Fm%2F015jr&gl=CA&ceid=CA%3Aen")

print(" Enter 1 for Alberta \n Enter 2 for BC \n ")

user_input= input()  # type: int


if user_input==1:

    lab= tk.Label(root,bg="yellow", text="Alberta")

    lab.pack()
    button = tk.Button(frame,
                       fg="red",
                       command=Alberta)

    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

elif user_input==2:

    button = tk.Button(frame,
                       fg="red",
                       command=BC)

    lab = tk.Label(root, text="British Columbia")

    lab.pack()

    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

else:

    print("Invalid input! Try Again!")

root.geometry('300x400')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Avoid mixing console input with GUI application.  What do you mean *"I cant seem to edit and format the button as I would like to"*?

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code to run it successfully -

```
import tkinter as tk (not with capital T)

if user_input=='1': 

elif user_input=='2':
```

The input() function, by default, will convert all the information it receives into a string. So you have comparet the input with string version.

Comment: OP is using Python 2 (as Tkinter is used), `input()` will return integer 1 if "1" is input.